# HD44780 based 20x4 LCD delays in printing

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, microchip, character-lcd

I am using my HD44780 based 20x4 LCD with the famous I2C backpack, AKA the I2C I/O expander module, the PCF8547, the I2C I/O expander module is connected to the 20x4 LCD and is connected via the I2C bus to my 8-bit PIC microcontroller, PIC18F4620.

Now what am I trying to do is have different menus on the LCD, each menu utilizes all the 80 characters on the display, and I use a rotary encoder to move between the menus.

Now the code for all of this is written and is indeed working.
My problem is a different story, my problem is that when I run the program, the first time I try to scroll through **all** the menus, there is a noticeable delay in printing the lines, to be very specific, sometimes there is a delay in the printing starting from the second line (counting from one not from zero as the LCD usually counts), and sometimes there is a delay in the printing starting from the third line. Now when I try to scroll again through **all** the menus, this noticeable delay is vanished, literally vanished, there is no delay, as it should be.
I've attached a URL to an unlisted YouTube video uploaded by me showing this full behavior from complete power-off state, I hope this is okay with the policy of the website.
https://youtu.be/ajXUXeMd_7U

As for the code, I will indeed post it, but I do not think there is a problem with the code at all, this is an interrupt driven code, with around 1k lines of code in the main file, I will only post the main function, the ISR, and the functions called in both of them which are related to this matter, if you need anything else please feel free to ask me, I am trying to ease things for you guys. :)

Constant Definitions (#define)

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ                  16e6
#define _INPUT                      1
#define _OUTPUT                     0
#define _HIGH                       1
#define _LOW                        0
#define _RISING_EDGE                1
#define _FALLING_EDGE               0
#define _MAX_NUMBER_OF_IDLE_SECONDS 30

#define _RTC_SQW_DIR                TRISBbits.TRISB0
#define _RTC_SQW_INTERRUPT          INT0IE
#define _RTC_SQW_INTERRUPT_FLAG     INT0IF

#define _ROTARY_SW_DIR              TRISBbits.TRISB1
#define _ROTARY_SW_INTERRUPT        INT1IE
#define _ROTARY_SW_INTERRUPT_FLAG   INT1IF
#define _ROTARY_CLK_DIR             TRISBbits.TRISB2
#define _ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT       INT2IE
#define _ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_FLAG  INT2IF
#define _ROTARY_CLK_PIN_READ        PORTBbits.RB2
#define _ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_ON    INTEDG2
#define _ROTARY_DT_DIR              TRISBbits.TRISB3
#define _ROTARY_DT_PIN_READ         PORTBbits.RB3

#define testLED_DIR                 TRISBbits.TRISB4
#define testLED_PIN_WRITE           LATBbits.LATB4
```

Main Routine:

```
void main(void)
{
// Inputs initialization
Inputs_Init();

// Outputs initialization
Outputs_Init();

// Peripherals initialization from in to out of the MCU.
I2C_Master_Init();
I2C_LCD_Init(LCD1_WRITE);
I2C_LCD_Clear(LCD1_WRITE);
DS3231_Init();
DHT22_Init();

// EEPROM Retrieval

// Interrupts initialization
Interrupts_Init();
while (1)
{
    // Section: Input


    // Section: Inputs Processing and Decision Taking 


    // Section: Output to User Interface
}
return;
}
```

ISR Routine:

```
void __interrupt() ISR(void)
{
if (_ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_FLAG)
{
    testLED_PIN_WRITE = _HIGH;
    if (_ROTARY_CLK_PIN_READ != _ROTARY_DT_PIN_READ)
    {
        // CW ==> ++
        if (rotarySetToChange)
        {
            cursorIncreaseValue();
        }
        else
        {
            cursorMoveToTheRight();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // CCW ==> --
        if (rotarySetToChange)
        {
            cursorDecreaseValue();
        }
        else
        {
            cursorMoveToTheLeft();
        }
    }
    cursorGoToCorrectPosition();
    testLED_PIN_WRITE = _LOW;
    idleSeconds = 0;
    _ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_ON = ~_ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_ON; // Adjust next interrupt edge.
    _ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_FLAG = _LOW;
}

if (_ROTARY_SW_INTERRUPT_FLAG)
{
    rotarySetToChange = ~rotarySetToChange;
    if (menu != 0)
    {
        if (rotarySetToChange)
        {
            I2C_LCD_BlinkON(LCD1_WRITE);
        }
        else
        {
            I2C_LCD_CursorON(LCD1_WRITE);
        }
    }
    idleSeconds = 0;
    _ROTARY_SW_INTERRUPT_FLAG = _LOW;
}
}
```

Used functions in the main and ISR routines

```
void Inputs_Init(void)
{
_RTC_SQW_DIR = _INPUT;

_ROTARY_SW_DIR = _INPUT;
_ROTARY_CLK_DIR = _INPUT;
_ROTARY_DT_DIR = _INPUT;
}

void Outputs_Init(void)
{
testLED_PIN_WRITE = _LOW;
testLED_DIR = _OUTPUT;
}

void Interrupts_Init(void)
{
GIE = 1; // General Interrupt Enable.
PEIE = 1; // Peripheral Interrupt Enable.

_RTC_SQW_INTERRUPT = 1; // RB0 Interrupt Enable, on rising edge by default. (INTEDG0 = 1)

rotaryAdjustNextInterruptEdge();
_ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT = 1; // Rotary Interrupt Enable.

_ROTARY_SW_INTERRUPT = 1; // Rotary Switch Interrupt Enable, on rising edge by default. 
 (INTEDG2 = 1)
 }

void cursorMoveToTheRight(void)
{
switch (menu)
{
case 0: // General Menu
    menu = 1;
    cursorRow = 3;
    cursorCol = 9;
    printStrings();
    break;
case 1: // Pigeons Door Time Menu
    cursorMoveRightInMenus_1234(2);
    break;
case 2: // Pigeons Food Time Menu
    cursorMoveRightInMenus_1234(3);
    break;
case 3: // Watering 1 Menu
    cursorMoveRightInMenus_1234(4);
    break;
case 4: // Watering 2 Menu
    cursorMoveRightInMenus_1234(5);
    break;
case 5: // Spraying Menu
    cursorMoveRightInMenus_5();
    break;
case 6: // Air Conditioner Menu
    cursorMoveRightInMenus_6();
    break;
case 7: // Temperature-Humidity Menu
    cursorMoveRightInMenus_7();
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveRightInMenus_1234(unsigned char newMenu)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        menu = newMenu;
        if (menu == 5)
        {
            cursorRow = 2;
            cursorCol = 9;
        }
        else
        {
            cursorRow = 3;
            cursorCol = 9;
        }
        printStrings();
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveRightInMenus_5(void)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 2:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 2;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 7;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 7:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 17;
        break;
    case 17:
        menu = 6;
        cursorRow = 2;
        cursorCol = 9;
        printStrings();
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveRightInMenus_6(void)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 2:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 2;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 6;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 6:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 17;
        break;
    case 17:
        menu = 7;
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 7;
        printStrings();
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveRightInMenus_7(void)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 7:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 19;
        break;
    case 19:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 7;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 7:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 19;
        break;
    case 19:
        menu = 0;
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 9;
        printStrings();
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveToTheLeft(void)
{
switch (menu)
{
case 0: // General Menu
    menu = 7;
    cursorRow = 4;
    cursorCol = 19;
    printStrings();
    break;
case 1: // Pigeons Door Time Menu
    cursorMoveLeftInMenus_1234(1);
    break;
case 2: // Pigeons Food Time Menu
    cursorMoveLeftInMenus_1234(2);
    break;
case 3: // Watering 1 Menu
    cursorMoveLeftInMenus_1234(3);
    break;
case 4: // Watering 2 Menu
    cursorMoveLeftInMenus_1234(4);
    break;
case 5: // Spraying Menu
    cursorMoveLeftInMenus_5();
    break;
case 6: // Air Conditioner Menu
    cursorMoveLeftInMenus_6();
    break;
case 7: // Temperature-Humidity Menu
    cursorMoveLeftInMenus_7();
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveLeftInMenus_1234(unsigned char newMenu)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        menu = newMenu - 1;
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 12;
        printStrings();
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveLeftInMenus_5(void)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 2:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        menu = 4;
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 12;
        printStrings();
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 2;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 2;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 7:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 17:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 7;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveLeftInMenus_6(void)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 2:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        menu = 5;
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 17;
        printStrings();
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 2;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 9:
        cursorRow = 2;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 12:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 9;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 6:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 12;
        break;
    case 17:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 6;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void cursorMoveLeftInMenus_7(void)
{
switch (cursorRow)
{
case 3:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 7:
        menu = 6;
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 17;
        printStrings();
        break;
    case 19:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 7;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    switch (cursorCol)
    {
    case 7:
        cursorRow = 3;
        cursorCol = 19;
        break;
    case 19:
        cursorRow = 4;
        cursorCol = 7;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}

void rotaryAdjustNextInterruptEdge(void)
{
if (_ROTARY_CLK_PIN_READ == _HIGH)
{
    _ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_ON = _FALLING_EDGE;
}
else
{
    _ROTARY_CLK_INTERRUPT_ON = _RISING_EDGE;
}
}

void printStrings(void)
{
I2C_LCD_CursorOFF(LCD1_WRITE);

switch (menu)
{
case 0: // General Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, humidityString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, temperatureString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, timeString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "   [General Menu]   ");
    break;
case 1: // Pigeons Door Time Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, pigeonsDoorTimeCloseString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, pigeonsDoorTimeOpenString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "    [Door  Time]    ");
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "   [Pigeons Menu]   ");
    break;
case 2: // Pigeons Food Time Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, pigeonsFoodTimeCloseString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, pigeonsFoodTimeOpenString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "    [Food  Time]    ");
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "   [Pigeons Menu]   ");
    break;
case 3: // Watering 1 Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, watering1ForString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, watering1OpenString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "        [1]         ");
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "     [Watering]     ");
    break;
case 4: // Watering 2 Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, watering2ForString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, watering2OpenString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "        [2]         ");
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "     [Watering]     ");
    break;
case 5: // Spraying Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, sprayingIntervalString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, sprayingToString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, sprayingFromString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "     [Spraying]     ");
    break;
case 6: // Air Conditioner Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, conditionerIntervalString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, conditionerToString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, conditionerFromString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "  [Air Conditioner] ");
    break;
case 7: // Temperature-Humidity Menu
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 4, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, temperatureAndHumidityMaxString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 3, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, temperatureAndHumidityMinString);
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 2, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "--------------------");
    I2C_LCD_Goto(1, 1, LCD1_WRITE);
    I2C_LCD_Print(LCD1_WRITE, "Temperature-Humidity");
    break;
}
}

void cursorGoToCorrectPosition(void)
{
switch (menu)
{
case 0: // General Menu, no Cursor
    break;
default:
    I2C_LCD_Goto(cursorCol, cursorRow, LCD1_WRITE);
    if (rotarySetToChange)
    {
        I2C_LCD_BlinkON(LCD1_WRITE);
    }
    else
    {

        I2C_LCD_CursorON(LCD1_WRITE);
    }
    break;
}
}
```

I do not want to go any further with the code, this is already exhausting, unless you want to.

A few things to summarize my thoughts, please note that the printStrings() function is called **before** the cursorGoToCorrrectPosition() function, so I am sure it is a hardware problem, maybe in the LCD it self?, because it prints a line or two out of four lines of strings, then it updates the cursor position *correctly* then it returns to print the remaining lines of strings.

My question is, why is there a delay at all? why is the delay only in the first scroll? how could I solve this delay?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you write every line of code? Or are you using any library routines between your code and the display hardware?

Comment: @jonk, yes I did write every line of code, even the libraries are mine, the I2C HW library and the PCF8574 I2C I/O expander module library.
And they are working and I've used the same HW before on a different project.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's an important addition. Your writing was informed and I was almost sure you'd say that you wrote it all. But I wasn't completely sure. So I asked. The thought that crossed my mind was *initialization* (such as a buffer pool) which might occur early and then not later on. But since you wrote it, then I think you'd know where to look for things like that. So I'll table that idea, now.

Comment: I think it is time you "instrumented" your code. Allocate an I/O pin for this and hook it to a scope. Use special sequential but fast pulses (make them up as you go) to identify where you are. Or if you have lots of I/O, you can be easier on yourself and just stuff a binary number out. Back in the day, we just laid an AM radio nearby and would learn to "hear" the music of different areas of the code running. Regardless, you need to narrow the turf. (Or someone here has to read your posted code better than I may.)

Comment: @jonk, Thanks to you in advance ^_^
If you mean the initialization of the LCD, it is properly initialized, you could see it in the first 10 seconds of the video, I put an intended delay of two seconds for the DHT22 to start up.
As for the "instrumented" code :), I do have a scope nearby, and I tried doing what you have said, you would not believe it, the one with noticeable delay is executed in a **shorter** time than the one with no delay at all, although it is the same code, precisely from 25ms and 50ms.

Comment: What do you know about the expander, itself? Is it possible that this is your problem? (I'm just trying to imagine anything that you aren't already in control of -- and that seems like the only thing.) Does it have any software (I've not looked up the device code, yet, sorry.) Or is it a pure hardware implementation IC?

Comment: @jonk, I do not really know much except for that fact that it is an I/O expander with two input lines SDA and SCL, and has 8 I/Os, this IC (PCF8574) (the expander) has 8 different selectable addresses, and an interrupt/reset pin to the microcontroller, which is typically not used on the breakout board/module, and let me tell you I think the problem is **not** in the expander but in the LCD itself.
Maybe there is some kind of a buffer somewhere? IDK, I am lost.
I tried looking at the datasheet before commenting back.

Comment: Most of those devices have an IC on them -- I think it's the one you named, or similar. (You can buy just the glass, but then you have to do a whole heck of a lot more work. So it's just not often found that way.) But I've used them. Both the 2 and the 4 line versions. I have a bunch of them in a box here, too. I've never experienced what you are talking about. Not once. They "just work." However, I've never tried to use them via I2C. So that's a difference.

Comment: Isn't the interface just 8 bits, a register select, read/write, and... an enable or something? It's pretty easy to use. (Been 6 years now, though.) Can you sacrifice some I/O and just operate it in parallel without the I2C? Just to see what happens then?

Comment: @Jonk, You are indeed correct, I am confused right now, I can think of a way to get around this, but I do wanna understand where the issue came from.

Comment: @Jonk, I was about to go and try that as well, but the reason behind I am using this I2C interface, is that I will need to hook up 10 relays eventually along with the I2C LCD, DS3231 RTC module, rotary encoder, and the DHT22, so that's a lot of pins and headache on the PCB design. I like to simplify things, if I can :)

Comment: I understood that and I know you have to get there, from here. But right now you need to isolate the problem. You can't fix it if you can't find the problem. Changing things up like this test several things and, in part, force you to revisit some parts of the code. When you write up a parallel driver routine for temporary testing, there will be some other adjustments to make all that work. Either way, you'll know something more after the test.

Comment: @jonk, you are correct once again, that's why I stopped immediately when I had a problem, I do not even have the logic for the control implemented yet, I do have an empty while(1) loop, and as for the parallel driver routine, I do have it ready as well, either 4-bit or 8-bit mode, I've written it before, I like developing and implementing my libraries and testing them extensively, that's why I think the problem is not in the code, because once again the same functions aka same SW is being called on the same HW, yet the HW acts different, anyways I will get back to you, thank you very much.

Comment: You sound like me. I thoroughly design and write code and then thoroughly test it in isolation before moving on. In critical medical equipment I may have to prove the results of all possible permutations of the inputs. All of my commercial and scientific software is still running, some for 30 years still. None has had a single big reported. My clients appreciate it very much ;)

Comment: It is an honor to sound like one of the top contributors and members in this website :).

I would love to learn from you anything I could learn ^_^
I hope you have time for me when I come back after testing extensively once again ^_^

Thanks again for your time,

Comment: How and what you write suggests that you care a lot about what you are doing. You are passionate. And it shows. I'm just recognizing what I see. Others are fortunate to have you helping them.

Comment: *the one with noticeable delay is executed in a shorter time than the one with no delay at all*. Worth investigating in more depth. Writing my own LCD driver using PCF8574, had a timing problem...adding delay fixed it. Every driver I've seen (including mine) writes blindly, never reads status. We expect the LCD chip to swallow every nybble with no feedback. On another note, de-bouncing rotary encoders with RC networks seems crude and error-prone, especially with interrupt-on-edge. I'd look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, like any other solution :)

I simply forgot to format the strings before printing them.

I have character arrays that hold each line to be printed on the LCD for each menu, and I do format them with sprintf, as it is the easiest way, but since I do have many menus and hence many lines and hence again many character arrays variables, I do not format them all, I only format the ones I need.
The problem was I **forgot** to call this function, so I print empty strings, so literally no change on the LCD happens, until an interrupt coming from the DS3231 RTC each second which formats the strings before printing them.
Now after I have scrolled through the whole menu, they are all formatted and ready to use already.

This has nothing to do with my code being bad, or my implementation being poor, it is simply that I forgot to call a function, my implementation is very user friendly and acts very quickly to the user interaction, and this is the main point in the project. I think my implementation is really good, it has proven itself to work flawlessly and quickly. If you have any other opinion, please share with details =)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If your lcd has some obscure defect, we’re not going to be able to help you. You could try another lcd to see if it behaves the same.
My money would be on the code causing the issue. Strip your code down to the bare minimum that exhibits the problem.

As a side note, having your program logic in an isr is bad juju. As well, having a rotary encoder generate interrupts is not good practice as well. Have a timer isr read the encoder pins and decode the state. Communicate the encoder position down to the main line code. Do the bare minimum in the isr. Try to minimise the number of interrupts and sources where possible. This is general advice - you can write your code anyway you like, but some ways are better than others.

Comment: I will replace the LCD tomorrow morning first thing, and will report back as well, I know you would bet your money on the code, it is a common mistake in the newbie's side :), but I am consider my self to be a beginner not a complete newbie :).
I broke down the code into blocks, I developed and tested each block alone to make sure it is running fine, and indeed it is, until that problem appeared, only when I developed and began to test the menus' code.

As for the side note, I thank you for that as well, but I have to clarify my idea and vision, maybe I am correct this time.. I hope so :)

Comment: The idea behind my project is to have a good user interface, by good I mean, easy and simple (its relative of course) and fast, and by fast I do mean literal fast, you push something you see the change immediately, you can't wait for the loop in while(1) to finish, I have developed indeed two versions before in this project, one with interrupt driven program and the other with the super loop program, the super loop program was definitely much slower and did not provide good user experience at all, that's why I moved over to the other program.

Comment: Please note that I am **not** implementing the **program logic** in the ISR, the logic is to be implemented in the main loop, for ISR is to handle the user interface tasks as fast as possible.

Comment: As for the rotary encoder, I do have a side problem with it yes, it reads sometimes backward for one turn, but I am leaving this problem for now, I know I could solve it with hardware, like tuning the resistors/capacitors values in the RC filter I implemented, or even use your approach of using a timer interrupt.

Once again I thank you very much for your advice and I do not mean any offense against you, I am merely expressing my opinion on why do I think my approach is better and I am very open to corrections from anyone.

We are here to learn mainly and I thank you all for your time.

Comment: The lcd has a response time of 100ms and you want microsecond response using an interrupt? Realistically you should be able to use no interrupts! Your initial poor response was due to poor implementation  not the technique.

Comment: @Abd-AlRahmanMuhammad You can do it your way and do heavy UI code in interrupts, but bear in mind that it may actually be one of the causes to your problem and it makes debugging it difficult. Embedded system experts have been against your opinion for decades now and there might be reasons why, but you can of course try yourself and prove the experts wrong. Best practices are just known to work, but it is possible to make it work with other practices as well. I do believe this is not a hardware problem but a software problem, and you can make a minimal test program to find out which is it.